# Can't use mplayer on 16.04 LTS X64

Tags: mplayer

When ever I try to use it gives this warning:

```
Error in skin config file at line 19: PNG read error in /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/skinb
```

followed by another warning

```
Config file processing error with skin 'default'
```

Comment: try reinstalling mplayer, perhaps that will solve the issue

Comment: done that already.

Comment: try running it in command line mode.  it always works for me there (using my *play* script that hunts for what i want to play and supports playlists)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to convert all .png files in `cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default` to png24.

You can use imagemagick:

```
for FILE in *.png ; do sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE ; done
```

Comment: `done` that and works. +1

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to completely reinstall mplayer along with configuration files. This should get rid of errors.

**Warning :** This will also remove custom configuration settings you have added (if any)!!

#### Completely remove mplayer

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mplayer
```

**Note** that because of `--purge` option, your **Global Configuration files** in `/etc/mplayer` will also be removed.

#### Remove Local Configuration files

```
 rm -r ~/.mplayer/
```

#### Now install mplayer back

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 16.10.